# PHP - Will uniqid() generate alphabetical IDs?

Tags: php, mysql, uniqueidentifier, alphabetical

If I use the PHP uniqid() function to generate IDs, and then I sort the IDs alphabetically in MySQL, will they be in the same order they were created?

It seems to me like they should be, since the IDs are just incrementing hexadecimal characters (at least I think they are), but does anyone know for certain?

Comment: just pressed f5 for a few seconds and it seems you're right, if you read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) it says "Gets a prefixed unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds."

Comment: a homework? isnt better to use a PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: I generally would use PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, but the primary key for this table _has_ to be a uniqid. So I wanted to confirm I wasn't missing anything before I move forward with this implementation.

Answer (score 5):

The uniqid() function generates a unique ID based on the microtime (current time in microseconds).

So I would probably say yes.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_uniqid.asp